# Are there any hosting solutions for asp.net and MongoDB out there?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, mongodb

I'm looking for hosting that provides both asp.net (prefer .net 4) and MongoDB. Anyone know any providers?

Comment: For anyone else stumbling in here, [Microsoft's Windows Azure cloud offers MongoDb](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/windows-azure/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongo has a list of available [commercial service providers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hosting+Center). Most of them are "private server" hosts. You're unlikely to find anything outside of privately hosted servers that will let you install Mongo on their system.

It's just too new, it's not like MySQL or SQL Server where many providers have just built separate farms for these things.

However, if you're already working with someone like "Maximum ASP.NET" and you just want to run a Mongo instance "somewhere", you can use [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com/home). They're basically just a hosted database provider.

It may mildly affect performance, but let's be fair, if you can't afford a VPS, you're probably not that worried about performance :)

Answer (score 16):

Micah:

Good question ... I am the founder of [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com) and we host MongoDB on top of multiple clouds (Amazon, Joyent, Rackspace, etc.). One of the companies that we have partnered with is [AppHabor](http://www.appharbor.com). They provide easy-to-use .NET application deployment and hosting and, through them, you can also provision MongoDB databases on MongoHQ and use us for your MongoDB hosting.

In general, this is the way that hosting is trending ... having people specialize in technologies and then partner together to provide the best experience.

Also, an important note to point out is that AppHarbor and the MongoHQ shared platform run inside the same network on Amazon. So, you get very low latency and the communication between your application and your database remains internal to the Amazon network. This is both good for speed and security.

I hope this helps. We have a great team that can answer additional questions if you have them! Good luck and happy deploying! :)

Jason